# convert mysql table data to string using php

Tags: php, mysql

suppose I have a mysql table like following:

```
     id value
     1   01
     2   03
     3   02
     4   15
     5   05
     6   04
     7   06
     8   10
     9   07
     10  09
     11  08
     12  11
     13  12
     14  14
     15  13
     16  16
```

How can I convert them to a string like this:

```
  01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are the rules here? Just get all rows from the table, and insert | after every 4th row (except the last set)?

Comment: Do you want to make the conversion in php or mysql?

Comment: yes, using php, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can always typecast a value to become a string:

```
$str = (string) $i["mysql_field"];
```

I think what you are looking is something like this (without knowing how your query is):

```
$counter = 0;
$result = "";
$sql = mysql_query(...);
while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result .= $i["value"];
    if ($counter == 3){
        $counter = 0;
        $result .= "|";
    }else{
        $result .= ",";
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

This will add the "|" character for every 4th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = "SELECT value FROM `your_table` ORDER BY id ASC";

$i = 0;
$string = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $i++;
    $string += $row['value'].',';
   if($i % 4 == 0){
     $string = substr_replace($string, '|',strlen($string) - 1, 1); 
   }    
}

$string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1);
```